# How can I import schemas required by a WSDL when using XML::Compile::WSDL11?

Tags: xml, perl, soap, xsd, wsdl

I want to build a client for a web-service using [`XML::Compile::WSDL11`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aWSDL11). This is the code I use:

```
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdlfile);
my $call = $wsdl->compileClient('MyMethod', port => 'MyPort');
$call->();
```

However, some operations return errors like this:

> error: cannot find ref element
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema'
>   at ...

AFAIC, this means that some schemas're missing. From the manpage:

> on purpose you must explicitly load
>   the files you need from local disk

How can I determine what schema files are required by the WSDL and import them automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required XSD file comes with `XML::Compile`. You can import it like this:

```
my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new($wsdlfile);
$wsdl->importDefinitions('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
```

See [`XML::Compile::Util`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKOV/XML-Compile-1.21/lib/XML/Compile/Util.pm) for the list of other schemas which can be imported this way.